# jQuery thickbox iframe with target div

Tags: jquery, iframe, inline, target, thickbox

Im trying to load a specific `<div>` id from a page within an `iframe`. Like a combination of iframed content and inline content.. Is that possible with thickbox?

Something like:

> < a
>   href="/**somepage.php**?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&**inlineId=SomeDIV-ID**" class="thickbox" />

Comment: No, but that's really easy to do with several of the other options recommended on the Thickbox homepage when support ended.

Answer (score 0):

As Mathletics mentioned above, Thickbox is no longer supported. One of the engines/scripts he mentions is colorbox (one of my favorites) which can be seen here:

http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

You'll notice as you look through the page various options one of which is:

`inline` : If true, content from the current document can be displayed by passing the href property a jQuery selector, or jQuery object.

```
// Using a selector:
$("#inline").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#myForm"});
```

I would try working with colorbox to achive your desired result. (It also supports iFrames)